# ${\rm order}(x)$ is infinite or ${\rm order}(h(x))$ divides ${\rm order}(x)$ even if we don't assume ${\rm order}(h(x))$ is finite right?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $A,B$ be groups with a homomorphism $h: A \to B$. Let $x,y \in A$.

I'm supposed to show that if $h(x)$ has finite order in $B$, then ${\rm order}(x)$ is infinite or ${\rm order}(h(x))$ divides ${\rm order}(x)=n < \infty$.

And of course the answer is

- https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Element_to_Power_of_Multiple_of_Order_is_Identity
- https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_Homomorphic_Image_of_Group_Element

What I'm wondering is the relevance of the assumption '$h(x)$ has finite order in $B$'. I think the only role it serves to make '${\rm order}(h(x))$' well-defined because actually I think the statement

> ${\rm order}(x)$ is infinite or ${\rm order}(h(x))$ divides ${\rm order}(x)$

is ('sensible' and) true because ${\rm order}(x) < \infty \implies{\rm order}(h(x)) < \infty$.

---

**Questions**:

1. Is the statement "${\rm order}(x)$ is infinite or ${\rm order}(h(x))$ divides ${\rm order}(x)$" true?
2. If not, then why not? If so, then am I right about the role of the assumption that ${\rm order}(h(x)) < \infty$ ?
3. Can we just say instead like

> Show that if ${\rm order}(x) < \infty$, then
>
> (A) ${\rm order}(h(x)) < \infty$ because ​${\rm order}(h(x)) \le{\rm order}(x)$
>
> - (the $(h(x))^n = h(x^n=1_A)=1_B$ part)
>
> (B) ${\rm order}(h(x))$ divides ${\rm order}(x)$
>
> - (the division algorithm part)

?

Comment: The statement "order is infinite, or finite and order $h(x)$ divides it" is of the form $\neg P \vee (P\wedge Q)$. This is equivalent to $P\to (P\wedge Q)$ (since $\neg A\vee B$ is equivalent to $A\to B$). Now, $P\to P$ is a tautology, and $(P\to A)\wedge (P\to B)$ is equivalent to $P\to(A\wedge B)$. So proving $P\to(P\wedge Q)$ is equivalent to proving $P\to Q$. Which in this situation, is precisely what you have in 3: "prove that if the order is finite, then the order of $h(x)$ divides the order of $x$". ((Note that your (B) implies your (A)). So.. yes, you can just do 3.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks. you're referring to 'Material implication' aka switcheroo?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I am refering to the standard implication that is used in mathematics. I have *never* heard it called "switcheroo", which to be honest, sounds rather like a dis.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin wait so [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) ? or not?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon: Yes, and as you see, the word "switcheroo"  is not on that page at all. Note that "switcheroo", as per OED, is "a change, reversal, or exchange, **especially a surprising or deceptive one.**" (emphasis added). Because of its connotation of surprise or desception, calling a completely standard mathematical interpretation a "suprise or deception" seems like a dis ("to treat with disrespect or contempt; to find fault with")

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ok but what about 'In his book Gödel, Escher, Bach, Douglas Hofstadter names one of the rules in his version of propositional calculus the Switcheroo Rule, apparently in honour of an Albanian railroad engineer, name Q. Q. Switcheroo, who "worked in logic on the siding".[5] This is in reality the material implication.' [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switcheroo) ?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what's your answer to Q1, Q2 please?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon: Are you truly not aware that the Hoftstadter statement is a **joke**? You really think there was an "Albanian railroad engineer named Q.Q. Switcheeroo"? Really? As to your second comment: I'm not at your beck and call. Had I wanted to answer the question, I would have. Poking me  in an attempt to get me to do the work for you is rather annoying, and unlikely to get me to reply any  further. Bye.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what work have i not done? For Q1 I'm asking if the original statement is true without the assumption. (sounds like answer is yes if you say yes to Q3...) For Q2 i'm just trying to understand the instructions here. but before i ask my instructor, i wanna be well equipped to say that the statement is indeed true without the assumption